# Want to distinguish between value and expression

Tags: lisp, expression

I'd like to know how I can distinguish between **'value'** and **'expression'**.

> In computer science, a value is an expression which cannot be
>   evaluated any further (a normal form).[1] The members of a type are
>   the values of that type.[1] For example, the expression 1 + 2 is not a
>   value as it can be reduced to the expression 3. This expression cannot
>   be reduced any further (and is a member of the type Nat) and therefore
>   is a value.

I found a statement above from the url below:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science) [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science))

From this statement I felt like:

> I think "value" look like the "atom" in chemistry based upon the
>   definition of Mitchell, John C.

But someone denied this:

> But, even expressions can be (represented as) values. The classic case
>   being an s-expression in Lisp-like languages. – user2864740

This talk is in another thread : what-is-the-value-in-1st-class-value [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34303757/what-is-the-value-in-1st-class-value)

It would have been so simple if user2864740 didn't say anything. But he said so and I am confused.

Could someone explain me about this situation? or the difference that might exist in **lisp like languages**?

Thank you in advance!

[1] Mitchell, John C. (1996). Foundations for Programming Languages. The MIT Press.

Comment: I think I would put more stock in the reasoning of John Mitchell than user2864740 ...

Comment: @John Hascall, I also only have to understand as John Mitchell's statement. I don't know about Lisp. Let me just forget s-expression thing...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because that's more a general computer science question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't know Lisp, read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) and play with some [Scheme](http://schemers.org/) implementation.

<sup>(the classic SICP book is a must read -it is a very good introductory book about programming-, so even if you know Lisp but didn't read SICP you really should read it; and it is freely available on-line.)</sup>

I strongly recommend reading C.Queinnec's [*Lisp In Small Pieces*](https://pages.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html) book, which explains how LISP interpreters or compilers expressions are designed, so cover your question is great details.

<sup>(actually your question needs an entire book to be answered, and Queinnec's book is that book)</sup>

LISP is an [homoiconic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) language, hence [*s-expressions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression) are values (but several values are *not* expressions, in particular [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29)). But most programming languages -C, Ocaml, Javascript, C++, Java, etc...- are (sadly) not homoiconic: their [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) is *not* a value and expressions cannot manipulate ASTs *natively*.

BTW, the wikipedia sentence

> a value is an expression which cannot be evaluated any further

is not always correct. For example, for the C language, values and expressions are different kind of beasts.

You should also read something about [formal semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_%28computer_science%29) of programming languages.

Also, reading Scott's [*Programming Language Pragmatics*](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/) will give you a broader view (thru *several* programming languages).

Comment: Thank you for providing us many links about many things I need to read. Maybe I need to read more than asking questions here.. Thank you..

Comment: I am afraid if I really understand those graceful functional languages - LISP, scheme, haskell. Someone told me that understanding functional paradigm requires more learning spend than OO paradigm. I spent much to learn about OO. To learn another good thing, I must gather/prepare more money/time/mind... Thank you though.. I am not a Jedi ^^;

Comment: That someone is wrong. Functional paradigm is easier than (and predates) OO. The SICP book is an introductory book to programming (and does not require any programming prerequisites)

Comment: And even C++11 has (at last!) some functional programming flavor. But you *should* read SICP first (and it is freely available online).

Comment: Thank you for cheer me up! O.K. Then I will try to read SICP. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

A value is a datum: the machine representation of some piece of information, such as a number or character string. The datum belongs to a *type* which has an associated *domain*: as set of all possible values of that type. The value is an element of that set.

An expression is a datum which represents syntax: usually a structured datum build as an aggregate (usually a tree structure) of other values. However, an individual non-aggregated value can also be an expression.

The purpose of an expression may be to denote the computation of a value; in that situation, ANSI Common Lisp refers to an expression as a *form*. Not all expressions are forms. For instance in `(let ((a 42)))`, `(a 42)` is an expression denoting, in the context of `let`, the variable `a` and its initializing form `42`, and `((a 42))` is an expression denoting the complete list of binding specifications under that `let`.

If a form is evaluated, and the result is a datum similar to that form itself, then one of the two is the case: the form might be a *literal* (a value which evaluates to itself if it is treated as an expression) or it might be a *quine*: a clever form which doesn't directly yield itself as a value (the way a literal does) but cleverly calculates an object which is structurally identical to itself.

A value is not defined as an expression which is irreducible and denotes itself; that is a literal constant.  A literal constant *denotes* a value. Values, however, exist in all contexts, such as the run-time context in which syntax is no longer relevant.  When a program is running, it can instantiate values which never exist as a piece of syntax. If we evaluate (+ 2 2), there is a 4 which never appeared in the syntax as the expression 4. Therefore we cannot say that the value 4 is an expression which is irreducible; the value exists even if no such expression does.